# Similar issue to: Multidimensional Array Find and Update The Value using PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am at a loss, I have seen similar posts but cannot get my array to have similar structure so that I can implement the solution:
I have an array that I create like this:

foreach ($lastsubresult as $lastselect) {
        array_push($finaldata_array, $subrecord->data ."=>". $lastselect->total );

and when I print this array the output is:

```
Array ( 
        [0] => aaaaa=>4 
        [1] => aaaaa=>3 
        [2] => aaaaa=>1 
        [3] => tyt=>2 
        [4] => tyt=>3 
      )
```

I would like to have only single aaaaa's and single tyt's in this array and to have the numbers added and like so:

```
[0] => aaaaa=>8
[1] => tyt=>5
```

or even,

```
[aaaaa] => 8
[tyt] => 5
```

I have looked at examples like:
$merged = array();

```
foreach ($finaldata_array as $answer) {
    if (isset($merged[$answer['answer']])) {
        $merged[$answer['answer']]['score'] += $answer['score'];
    } else {
        $merged[$answer['answer']] = $answer;
    }
}

var_dump($merged);
```

but cannot seem to get my array to be similar to the example. The example is exactly what I want to achieve. Could my array_push be wrong.

I will greatly appreciate your help.
Thank you very much.
Christopher

Comment: `[0] => aaaaa=>4` : this isn't a multidimensional array. This is a string in an array. Your array_push isn't doing what you think it does.

Answer (score 1):

I can only try to guess what your data is like, but what you're trying to do would be something like this :

```
foreach($lastsubresult as $lastselect)
{
    $finaldata_array[$subrecord->data] = isset($finaldata_array[$subrecord->data]) ? $finaldata_array[$subrecord->data] + $lastselect->total : $lastselect->total;
}
```

or, if you don't like / aren't familiar with the ternary operator ? :

```
foreach($lastsubresult as $lastselect)
{
    if(!isset($finaldata_array[$subrecord->data]))
    {
        $finaldata_array[$subrecord->data] = $lastselect->total;
    }
    else
    {
        $finaldata_array[$subrecord->data] += $lastselect->total;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello @Kethryweryn. Thank you so much for your post. I am implementing now and will come back with results. Have a great weekend.

Comment: Yip, your solution works like a charm :D You are my hero for the whole weekend.

Comment: @Christopher Van Heerden then don't forget to accept the answer. ;)